# Hibernate : Lock a row while update, so user's don't retrieve a counter from it

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which I am using Hibernate as the ORM, PostgreSQL as our DB and in one of our Objects(GroupCanvas), we have a number which is incremented everytime when user takes some action, and then the GroupCanvas object is updated in DB, and it should be unique.

THe problem we have currently is, if multiple users take action in front-end, some of them are getting duplicate numbers. We are working on fixing this now, so later we can implement a sequence and are assured that the numbers are unique.

How can I ensure that when I am updating the row, other users are waiting till the row is updated. I tried LockMode.Pessimistic_write, and a few others, none helped.

Code :

```
  @Override
    public void incrementNoteCounterForGroupCanvas(int canvasId) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.flush();
        Query query = session.createQuery("update GroupCanvas as gc set gc.noteCount=gc.noteCount+1 where gc.mcanvasid=:canvasId");
        query.setParameter("canvasId",canvasId);
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.flush();
    }

 @Override
    public GroupCanvas getCanvasById(int mcanvasid) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.flush();
        return (GroupCanvas) session.get(GroupCanvas.class, mcanvasid,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    }
```

Both methods are in DAO, which has `@Transactional` annotation, and annotation present in service layer as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the solution you're looking for exist in the read options of ProgressSql ? Because if Progress don't allow to do so, you'll can't implement it in your code.

Comment: An update automatically lock the row. In your code, the entity is  fetched then updated but the row can change between the select and the update. You should lock the row prior to update the row. The simpler is to issue an atomic update statement `UPDATE GROUPCANVAS SET COUNTER = COUNTER +1`.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot : I will change it to the query you said, can you tell me how I can lock the row for read, as I dont have an object to lock, I just have the ID(primary-key) by which I retrieve.

Comment: For example `em.find(GroupCanvas.class,  id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)`. To be tested, I'm not sure if the session cache interfere with this query if the entity has already been fetched. If yes, you should flush it (or just invalidate the entity).

Comment: @NicolasLabrot : I did what you said, didn't help, please check updated code.

Comment: Now I am actually getting 4 duplicates instead of 2... :-(

Comment: strange. You get 4 duplicates even if you replace the code of Ruben by the HQL update statement? If your requirements are only to increment the value, a lock should not be necessary, it add extra queries whereas an update already lock the row

Comment: @NicolasLabrot : No, that I got when I implemented the pessimistic write thing as u had suggested. Sorry.. :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the method you have posted the usage if the 'LOCKING' technique is not quite correct. In order for a lock to end up with the result you are looking for the sequence of actions should be similar to the ones below (in the nutshell it is similar to the Double-Checked Locking but implemented using DB locks - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

1. Start the transaction (eg `@Transactional` annotation on your service method)
2. Retrieve entity from database with the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock mode (make sure to indicate hibernate that fresh copy should be read instead of the one stored in session cache)
3. If required check the current value of the target field if it meets your invariants
4. Perform the change/update on the field (eg, increment the value of a field )
5. Save the entity (and make sure to flush the value to the DB if you do not want to wait for the auto-flush)
6. Commit the transaction (done automatically when using `@Transactional`)

The essential difference of this sequence when compared with the posted method is that **the update of the property value is performed while your transaction holds a lock on the target entity/db row**, hence preventing other transactions from reading it while your update is in progress.

Hope this helps .

**UPDATE:** 
I believe something like the code snippet bellow should work as expected :

```
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public void incrementNoteCounterForGroupCanvas(int canvasId) {
            final Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            final GroupCanvas groupCanvas = session.get(GroupCanvas.class, canvasId,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
            session.refresh(groupCanvas);
            groupCanvas.setNoteCount(groupCanvas.getNoteCount()+1);
            session.saveOrUpdate(groupCanvas);
            session.flush();
        }
```

Comment: Our dao and service layer both have transactional annotation, object retrieved with pessimistic_write mode, didn't help. Can you please check updated code. Thank you.

Comment: Added a code snippet to the answer, I think this should solve the problem. (did not have an IDE open, so sorry for the compilation errors if any :-) )

Comment: This solved the problem, I just called session.merge instead of session.save as the object already exists in DB. I hope that's fine. :-)

Comment: Cool ! Only one last remark , if the entity/row already exists in the DB then you might better use "session.saveOrUpdate" , "merge" also would work, however, it performs extra actions like associating detached entity to the session. Looking on the provided example that step is not really required. So I would just use "saveOrUpdate" to keep it more clear and simple (unless you need "merge" for some other reason as well)

Comment: This code execute 3 statements, 1) a lock, 2) a select to refresh, 3) an update. An update already locks the row at the DB level, If you are looking for efficiency,  `update GroupCanvas as gc set gc.noteCount=gc.noteCount+1 where gc.mcanvasid=:canvasId` should do the job too

Comment: Due to realtime nature, we require that the object is update throughout including the detached session, thus the merge.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot : Doing only that didn't solve the problem adding these locks as well solved it. Please post an answer for upvote. Thank you.

Comment: It's very strange you should add a lock before the HQL update. An answer will not help I think,  I will not bother you with this.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot as I understood from the previous comments guys not only update the counter but the other properties of the Entity as well (prior, during or after the increment). Hence , I assume, that that second update also overrides the change performed by the HQL query you have suggested. However, I agree with you that if it would be only the increment of the counter(without a save/update of other properties/fields on the same row) then HQL method you have proposed should work fine without extra locks as well  (and with less DB roundtrips).

Comment: Yes, I think too.

Comment: What is the row is not yet in the DB? final GroupCanvas groupCanvas = session.get(GroupCanvas.class, canvasId,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE); will return null, but once I call session.saveOrUpdate(groupCanvas); session.flush(); will it get locked? If I try to lock right after, I get an exception stating that entity has been updated by a different transaction although there is no other transaction.